# How to use R's loop to get the part of the aggregate matrix other than the many subset matrices?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, aggregate, subset

I have two matrices of pure numbers, and their format is the same: the first column is the group name, the second is the starting number, and the third is the ending number. Each group is the name of a chromosome. All data were transformed from fasta data. I am trying to generate a blacklist(table3) with the whitelist(table2) by taking the whole genome(table1) as the base.

E.g (*spaces in the following tables represent column change):
A row of table1:

```
scahrs1_999 1 12
```

#Means the total set of numbers for the 'scahrs1_999' group is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.

Some rows of table2:

```
scahrs1_999 2 3
scahrs1_999 6 8
scahrs1_999 11 12
```

#Means that the subsets of numbers in the 'scahrs1_999' group are '2, 3', '5, 6, 7', and '10, 11'.

The result I want to get is a set of numbers that do not contain any subsets in the total set, and behaves the same as a subset of table2's consecutive numbers. which is:

table3 (results):

```
scahrs1_999 1
scahrs1_999 4 5
scahrs1_999 9 10
scahrs1_999 13 14
```

Also exclude subsets with only 1 number. which is:

table3 (final result):

```
scahrs1_999 4 5
scahrs1_999 9 10
scahrs1_999 13 14
```

As shown below, I have a number of groups similar to the above 'scahrs1_999'. Obviously, I can't calculate them one by one. I know that R can loop through each group with a 'loop program' and get the corresponding result. But my programming ability is not up to this complex job.

```
> Table1

1  scahrs1_1001  1     81142
2  scahrs1_1002  1     62661
3  scahrs1_1003  1    104891
4  scahrs1_1004  1     99296
5  scahrs1_1005  1     30919
6  scahrs1_1006  1     97599
7  scahrs1_1008  1     97078
8  scahrs1_1009  1     96958
9  scahrs1_1010  1     45677

> Table2

1  scahrs1_1001      1    753
2  scahrs1_1001  14931  15932
3  scahrs1_1001  17007  18008
4  scahrs1_1001  21211  22212
5  scahrs1_1001  40908  41909
6  scahrs1_1001  63233  64234
7  scahrs1_1001  76009  77010
8  scahrs1_1002   1068   2069
9  scahrs1_1002  12992  13993
10 scahrs1_1002  40448  41449
11 scahrs1_1003   2227   3228
12 scahrs1_1003  18453  19454
13 scahrs1_1003  28679  29680
14 scahrs1_1003  41161  42162
15 scahrs1_1003  41735  42736
16 scahrs1_1003  43040  44041
17 scahrs1_1003  64416  65417
18 scahrs1_1003  71219  72220
19 scahrs1_1003  96090  97091
20 scahrs1_1003  97306  98307
21 scahrs1_1004   1554   2555
22 scahrs1_1004  29086  30087
23 scahrs1_1004  44100  45101
24 scahrs1_1004  47799  48800
25 scahrs1_1004  59550  60551
26 scahrs1_1004  69356  70357
27 scahrs1_1004  71809  72810
28 scahrs1_1004  84272  85273
29 scahrs1_1004  89034  90035
30 scahrs1_1004  98627  99628
31 scahrs1_1005   6695   7696
32 scahrs1_1005  30160  31161
33 scahrs1_1006    298   1299
34 scahrs1_1006  70134  71135
35 scahrs1_1006  93750  94751
36 scahrs1_1008   3859   4860
37 scahrs1_1008   5575   6576
38 scahrs1_1008   7072   8073
39 scahrs1_1008   9342  10343
40 scahrs1_1008  11814  12815
41 scahrs1_1008  15290  16291
42 scahrs1_1008  40167  41168
43 scahrs1_1008  42890  43891
44 scahrs1_1008  44806  45807
45 scahrs1_1008  74442  75443
46 scahrs1_1008  82112  83113
47 scahrs1_1008  93766  94767
48 scahrs1_1008  95233  96234
49 scahrs1_1009   8000   9001
50 scahrs1_1009  37369  38370
51 scahrs1_1009  53086  54087
52 scahrs1_1009  83722  84723
53 scahrs1_1009  90044  91045
54 scahrs1_1010  11341  12342
55 scahrs1_1010  33500  34501
56 scahrs1_1010  34931  35932
57 scahrs1_1010  37937  38938
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show small reproducible example instead of images

Comment: Sorry, how could I use dput?

Comment: Once you read the data i.e. `table1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv')`, then use `dput(head(table1, 10))` and copy/paste the output in your post

Comment: Thx, I am making it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of the data is jumbled, but I believe this `data.table` solution will return the desired `Table3` (modifying the posted dataset slightly to correct the mistakes):

```
library(data.table)

Table1 <- data.table(group = c("scahrs1_1", "scahrs1_10", "scahrs1_100", "scahrs1_1000", "scahrs1_1001", "scahrs1_1002", "scahrs1_1003", "scahrs1_1004", "scahrs1_1005", "scahrs1_1006", "scahrs1_1008"), idxStart = 1L, idXEnd = c(1870329L, 925472L, 187969291L, 99113L, 81142L, 62661L, 104891L, 99296L, 30919L, 97599L, 97078L))
Table2 <- data.table(group = c(rep("scahrs1_1", 11), rep("scahrs1_10", 2)), idxStart = c(8158L, 17916L, 18644L, 31439L, 37022L, 62954L, 123548L, 129802L, 135683L, 135942L, 172435L, 22999L, 39260L), idxEnd = c(9159L, 18917L, 19645L, 32440L, 38023L, 63955L, 124549L, 130803L, 136684L, 136943L, 173436L, 24000L, 40261L))

fBetween <- function(grp, idxStart, idxEnd) {
  idxRange <- unlist(Table1[group == grp, 2:3])
  if (idxStart[1] == idxRange[1]) {
    if (last(idxEnd) == idxRange[2]) {
      list(idxStart = first(idxEnd, -1) + 1, idxEnd = last(idxStart, -1) - 1)
    } else {
      list(idxStart = idxEnd + 1, idxEnd = c(last(idxStart, -1) - 1, idxRange[2]))
    }
  } else {
    if (last(idxEnd) == idxRange[2]) {
      list(idxStart = c(idxRange[1], first(idxEnd, -1) + 1), idxEnd = idxStart - 1)
    } else {
      list(idxStart = c(idxRange[1], idxEnd + 1), idxEnd = c(idxStart - 1, idxRange[2]))
    }
  }
}

Table3 <- setorder(Table2, group, idxStart)[, fBetween(first(group), idxStart, idxEnd), group][idxStart != idxEnd]
Table3
#>          group idxStart  idxEnd
#>  1:  scahrs1_1        1    8157
#>  2:  scahrs1_1     9160   17915
#>  3:  scahrs1_1    18918   18643
#>  4:  scahrs1_1    19646   31438
#>  5:  scahrs1_1    32441   37021
#>  6:  scahrs1_1    38024   62953
#>  7:  scahrs1_1    63956  123547
#>  8:  scahrs1_1   124550  129801
#>  9:  scahrs1_1   130804  135682
#> 10:  scahrs1_1   136685  135941
#> 11:  scahrs1_1   136944  172434
#> 12:  scahrs1_1   173437 1870329
#> 13: scahrs1_10        1   22998
#> 14: scahrs1_10    24001   39259
#> 15: scahrs1_10    40262  925472
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can be applied after grouping the two data.tables

```
f <- function(s,e,is,ie) {
  res = t(rbindlist(list(c(
      list(c(s[1],is[1]-1)),
      lapply(2:length(is), \(i) c(ie[i-1]+1, is[i]-1)),
      list(c(ie[length(ie)]+1, e[length(e)]))
  ))))
  list(start = res[,1], end = res[,2])
}
```

Usage (Using `Table1` and `Table2`, courtesy of @jblood94)

```
Table1[Table2, on="group"][, f(idxStart, idxEnd, i.idxStart,i.idxEnd), by=group][start<end]
```

Output:

```
         group  start     end
 1:  scahrs1_1      1    8157
 2:  scahrs1_1   9160   17915
 3:  scahrs1_1  19646   31438
 4:  scahrs1_1  32441   37021
 5:  scahrs1_1  38024   62953
 6:  scahrs1_1  63956  123547
 7:  scahrs1_1 124550  129801
 8:  scahrs1_1 130804  135682
 9:  scahrs1_1 136944  172434
10:  scahrs1_1 173437 1870329
11: scahrs1_10      1   22998
12: scahrs1_10  24001   39259
13: scahrs1_10  40262  925472
```

Comment: Although your code shows an error in my R studio, thank you for your help.